# Dataview overlaps on each other ExtJs?

Tags: extjs

I am reloading stores of dataview by ajax calls,
and my dataviews are like below but second(`result1`) and third(`result2`) view is overlapping to each other after stores are loaded in view.

```
Ext.define('newTab', {
    layout  :   {
                    type: 'border',
                    padding: 5
                },
    extend  :   'Ext.Panel',
    alias   :   'widget.newTab',
    id      :   'newTab',
    margin  :   '10 15 10 15',
    border  :   true,
    items   :   [   Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {   // List of SAP levels section (Upper one)
                               store : store,
                                 tpl : resultTemplate,
                        itemSelector : 'div.list-item',
                              region : "north",
                              margin : '0px 0px 10px 0px',
                              //autoScroll : true,
                           emptyText : '<div class="noDataText"> Looks like we couldn\'t find anything! <div>', // Empty data Message

                    }),
                    Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
                        tpl : Ext.XTemplate('<div id="result1"></div>'),
                        maxHeight:100,
                    }),
                    Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
                        tpl : Ext.XTemplate('<div id="result2"></div>')                 
                    }),
                ]
});
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: result1 and result2 are currently both fighting for the center region. Maybe add ```region:'south'``` to result2 view.

Comment: adding region south would not work for me as it takes it down and it has more data so its not visible by doing it. I want to display all of them one after another.

Comment: The border layout has no center region.

Comment: Is there anyway to show them one after another ?

Comment: Wrap ```result1``` and ```result2``` views in a ```container``` with ```vbox``` layout.

Comment: can you please post the sample code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved by changing layout type.

```
layout  :   {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch',
                padding: 5
             }
```